# How to limit the number of votes in 'acts_as_votable' gem

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I'm currently using the rubygem **[acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)** as the voting system in my project, but I want to limit the total votes of every user (which I used rubygem **[devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)**)

The target of the vote is a model called `Pin`:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_votable 
end
```

Should I use a `method` and put it in the `before_action:` to make sure that the vote your making won't let your total votes exceed say like 10?

Updated: 8/18/2015

Now I popped up with a new question:
I created another model `group`, and declaim the relationship:

(group.rb)

```
has_many: pins
```

(pin.rb)

```
belongs_to: group
```

So, here comes up the question, if I want to limit the votes in **every** group, say like: 10 in group 1, 10 in group 2, 10 in group 3....

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
   # check for user's total votes
  if current_user.find_voted_items.size < 10
    @pin.vote_by :voter => current_user
  else
    ..... #your code
    flash[:notice] = "your total votes exceed"
    redirect_to pins_path
  end
end
```

Comment: @JoeyCheng : Glad to help you

Comment: I  have another question, please help me solve it if you have time, thank you. @GaganGami

Comment: @JoeyCheng : Yes sure. You can post your new question on SO with required information and issue you face